# How to use $(this) selector to get attributes of list of items after clicking button

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to add checkbox to list of items (links) after pressing a button.

The idea is that I got list of links such as:

- Google.com.
- Bing.com
- Cnn.com

etc, And I got button at the bottom of the page, once the button is clicked I want to add checkbox for each link, but each box id should be the serial number of the link it's attached to.

```
$("#links_remove").click(function(event) {


$('.links').after('<div><label> Check box to remove link: <input type="checkbox" class=" removebox" id="'+$(this).attr("id").split("_")[1]+'"></div>');
});
```

And this is the HTML

```
<a class="links" id="link_27" href="google.com">google.com</a>
```

But of course the $(this) selector get the attributes of the button ("links_remove") and not of the current link.

Thanks!

Comment: Of course `this` is referring to the button, because that is the element that dispatched the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *function* argument to `after()` inside which `this` will point to the current link.

```
$("#links_remove").click(function(event) {
    $('.links').after(function(index) {

        // here "this" refers to the current ".link" and not "#links_remove"

        return '<div><label> Check box to remove link: <input type="checkbox" class=" removebox" id="'+this.id.split("_")[1]+'"></div>';
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr("id")` can safely be replaced with `this.id`.

Comment: @Blender - Totally, infact `this.id` is faster and cleaner as well.

Comment: Yup, I hopped to avoid using functions, but it was actually quite simple. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should get the job done:

```
$('.links').each(function(){
    $(this).after('<div><label> Check box to remove link: <input type="checkbox" class=" removebox" id="'+$(this).attr("id").split("_")[1]+'"></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used a for-each loop to get all the links: http://jsfiddle.net/ehV9L/

```js
$("#links_remove").click(function (event) {
    $('.links').each(function () {
        $(this).after('<span><label> Check box to remove link: <input type="checkbox" class="removebox" id="' + $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1] + '"></span>');
    });
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a class="links" id="link_01" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
    <li><a class="links" id="link_02" href="http://www.bing.com">Bing</a></li>
    <li><a class="links" id="link_03" href="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</a></li>
</ul>
<input type="button" id="links_remove" value="Remove Links" />
```